# How to fetch particular elements from a array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

How to fetch particular elements from a array using jquery ? Lets say I have an array

```
var arr = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5, Obj6]
```

I get the index of objects I need to select, say 3 and 5. Is there a efficient way to do it ? Something like

```
var result = arr.someFunction([3, 5])
```

Comment: You can do this with javascript 'classes' and prototyping.

Comment: You will still implement the code under the hood, but do it once and you can reuse it throughout your app: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You could well add a prototype method to do this :) example:

```
#this adds the a new method called "getElementsAt" to the array object
Array.prototype.getElementsAt=function(elements)
{
    var outputarray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        outputarray[i] = this[elements[i]];
    }
    return outputarray;
}

#then do your thing
var arr = ["item0","item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"]
var result = arr.getElementsAt([3, 5])
```